# How to stop accumulation of stdout from process?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, popen

So I'm reading the stdout of many processes using the
`await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(args,stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,limit=self.chunk_size)`, and getting the stdout from the results of await. What's returned is asyncio's StreamReader, in which I use the`read(self.chunk_size)` coroutine toput each chunk in a queue, which is processed by some threads.

It's able to run fine, but I'm dealing with high amounts of stdout, and I see the memory usage increase slowly.

What I'm confused, is why the memory usage continues to ramp up when I'm limiting the buffer size of what's being written to stdout. I thought setting the limit would limit the data being read, and stay constant.

Thanks for any insight!

Edit:
A minimal running example using tshark. You can get an example pcap from [here](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PcapFiles)

I actually saw that running this example with the yes command and iostat -t 1 command, I did not run into this issue. But I did with this tshark command.
running on python 3.6

```
import asyncio,sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import Thread
from shlex import quote

q = Queue()
chunk_size = 8192 
async def yes_command():
        args = ' '.join(["tshark", "-r", quote(sys.argv[1]),"-T", "fields", "-e", "eth.src", "-e", "eth.dst", "-e", "ip.src", "-e", "ip.dst", "-e", "ip.proto", "-e", "tcp.srcport", "-e", "tcp.dstport", "-e", "udp.srcport", "-e", "udp.dstport", "-E", "separator=@"])
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(args,stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,limit=chunk_size)
        #this is a Stream Reader
        return process.stdout


async def test():
    streamer = await yes_command()

    registered = set()
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(streamer.read(chunk_size))
    registered.add(task)
    while registered:
        done,pending = await asyncio.wait(
            registered, timeout=None, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
        )
        if not done:
            break
        for f in done:
            registered.discard(f)
            res = f.result()
            q.put(res)
            if res != b'':
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(streamer.read(chunk_size))
                registered.add(task)
            else:
                q.put(None)


    return 'done' 

### A very simple worker
def worker(q):
    while True:
        res = q.get()
        ### do something with res
        if res is None:
            print("none")
            break

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    task_list = []

    consumer = Thread(target=worker,args=(q,))
    consumer.daemon=True
    consumer.start()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ### alter range value to spawn x tshark processes.
    for i in range(5):
        task_list.append(test())
    
    commands = asyncio.gather(*task_list)
    result = loop.run_until_complete(commands)
    consumer.join()
    loop.close()
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a _minimal runnable example_ that shows the issue. For example, a program that spawns the `yes` utility (which provides infinite output) and processes its output in a trivial way that shows this unlimited memory consumption.

Comment: I added some code that reflects what I'm trying to do. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your answer fixes the immediate issue, there is still the underlying problem that your queue has unlimited capacity, leaving you vulnerable to unbounding accumulation of memory. Without *backpressure* (ability to pause the producer), you have a memory problem whenever the queue consumer is consistently slower than the producer, and it's hard to guarantee that that will never happen, especially in production.

I'd recommend switching to a bounded queue for backpressure. To do that, you cannot use `queue.Queue` because it would block, you need `asyncio.Queue`. You would need to:

- create the queue with `asyncio.Queue(10)` - you can use any positive number for capacity.
- enqueue data with `await q.put(res)` - `q.put` suspends until there is a free slot in the queue, providing backpressure)
- retrieve data using `res = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(loop, q.get()).result()` - you need `run_coroutine_threadsafe` because the event loop is running in a different thread.

Also, your loop that transfers the subprocess output to the queue seems unnecessarily complicated. (Perhaps it's a remnant of simplification from the more complex actual code.) I would suggest doing it with a simple loop:

```
async def test():
    streamer = await yes_command()
    while True:
        data = await streamer.read(chunk_size)
        if data == b'':
            await q.put(None)
            break
        await q.put(data)
```

If you need to run multiple such producers in parallel, you can just start multiple coroutines all running the above loop - you don't need to juggle readers in an explicit set.

Comment: Thanks for your insight/improvements. Yes I do believe a bounded asyncio Queue would be best for that added security as well as concurrency. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave this here, in case anyone has the same issue.

Changing the `read` line to `readexactly()` fixed the issue. The issue was that `read` only read up to a very small cap, which appended a lot of info to my queue, which wasn't being dequeued fast enought. Just tested the fix with large outputs, and got what I needed.

Comment: Note that `readexactly` will raise an exception if it can't read exactly the requested size. You might want to examine how your program behaves when the subprocess finishes.